# How to take screenshot of CSS 3D Renderer in Three JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html2canvas

I have a Three JS application that involves CSS 3D Renderer. I am using html2canvas library to take screenshots of document.body.

The only problem is that it takes a screenshot of everything except the CSS 3D Renderer.

Here's the code for taking the screenshot:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){

    //Listen to 'P' key
    if(e.which !== 80) return;

    html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL();
        window.open( img , 'Final' );
      }
    });
});
```

For a demo, please visit:

http://nobelbrothers.com/test/CanvasShot and http://nobelbrothers.com/CanvasShot

Note: Press P to take a screenshot (You need to turn off pop-up blocker).

Thank you

Comment: I don't believe any of the html to canvas renderers handle 3D CSS.

Comment: Then is there an alternative way to sync CSS 3D Scenes across multiple displays/screens @gman?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this feature thanks to the [file saver js lib](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filesaver.js"></script>

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){

    //Listen to 'P' key
    if(e.which !== 80) return;
    Render.domElement.toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "Final");
    });
});
```